# TFS VSO build 2015 not showing console output

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

I am having an issue with the new TFS build. When I run a build then the console output appears. 
[image]

But when the build finishes then the consle output disappears and there is no way to see what happened during the build. The console output is completly missing
[image]

On the logs of the VSOAgent I find the following ERROR. Maybe it has something to do with it. It says access denied but the user is admin on both the TFS server and the agent server:

```
[a06a0975-b891-44ac-9010-a10717e0696c][33486819-a9aa-4d4d-953b-b3762b4d1071]Record: t=MavenBuild, n=E:\AgentJ7_1\_work\1\s\siena-parent\pom.xml, s=Initialized, st=06/01/2016 16:00:38, 0%, ft=, r=: 
16:00:38.406359 LogFileTimer_Callback - enter (79)
16:00:38.406359 LogFileTimer_Callback - processing job 467d364f-05e4-49c5-a3fd-0134d0889e4f
16:00:38.406359 LogFileTimer_Callback - found 1 records for job 467d364f-05e4-49c5-a3fd-0134d0889e4f
16:00:38.421999 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
16:00:38.421999 System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi.TaskOrchestrationPlanSecurityException: Access denied: TFSSERVICE does not have write permissions for orchestration plan ccf1ea00-caec-4c73-9439-ee531f24eddc.
16:00:38.421999    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
16:00:38.421999    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__49.MoveNext()
16:00:38.421999 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
16:00:38.421999    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
16:00:38.421999    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
16:00:38.421999    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
16:00:38.421999    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__47`1.MoveNext()
16:00:38.421999 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
16:00:38.421999    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
16:00:38.421999    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
16:00:38.421999    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__53`1.MoveNext()
16:00:38.421999 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
16:00:38.421999    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
16:00:38.421999    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
16:00:38.421999    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__52`1.MoveNext()
16:00:38.421999    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
16:00:38.421999    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
16:00:38.421999    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.JobWriter.UploadAttachment(Guid timelineId, Guid timelineRecordId, String type, String name, String path, Boolean deleteSource, TimelineRecord& attachmentUpdataRecord)
16:00:38.421999 ---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi.TaskOrchestrationPlanSecurityException: Access denied: TFSSERVICE does not have write permissions for orchestration plan ccf1ea00-caec-4c73-9439-ee531f24eddc.
16:00:38.421999    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
16:00:38.421999    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__49.MoveNext()
16:00:38.421999 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
16:00:38.421999    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
16:00:38.421999    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
16:00:38.421999    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
16:00:38.421999    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__47`1.MoveNext()
16:00:38.421999 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
16:00:38.421999    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
16:00:38.421999    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
16:00:38.421999    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__53`1.MoveNext()
16:00:38.421999 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
16:00:38.421999    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
16:00:38.421999    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
16:00:38.421999    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__52`1.MoveNext()<---
16:00:38.421999 
16:00:38.421999    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
16:00:38.421999    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.JobWriter.UploadAttachment(Guid timelineId, Guid timelineRecordId, String type, String name, String path, Boolean deleteSource, TimelineRecord& attachmentUpdataRecord)
16:00:38.421999 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
16:00:38.421999 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
16:00:38.421999 Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi.TaskOrchestrationPlanSecurityException: Access denied: TFSSERVICE does not have write permissions for orchestration plan ccf1ea00-caec-4c73-9439-ee531f24eddc.
16:00:38.421999    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
16:00:38.421999    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__49.MoveNext()
16:00:38.421999 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
16:00:38.421999    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
16:00:38.421999    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
16:00:38.421999    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
16:00:38.421999    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__47`1.MoveNext()
16:00:38.421999 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
16:00:38.421999    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
16:00:38.421999    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
16:00:38.421999    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__53`1.MoveNext()
16:00:38.421999 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
16:00:38.421999    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
16:00:38.421999    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
16:00:38.421999    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__52`1.MoveNext()
16:00:38.421999    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
16:00:38.421999    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__49.MoveNext()
16:00:38.421999 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
16:00:38.421999    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
16:00:38.421999    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
16:00:38.421999    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
16:00:38.421999    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__47`1.MoveNext()
16:00:38.421999 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
16:00:38.421999    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
16:00:38.421999    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
16:00:38.421999    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__53`1.MoveNext()
16:00:38.421999 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
16:00:38.421999    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
16:00:38.421999    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
16:00:38.421999    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__52`1.MoveNext()
16:00:38.421999 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
16:00:38.421999 LogFileTimer_Callback - leave
16:00:38.562615 ConsoleTimer_Callback - enter (80)
16:00:38.562615 ConsoleTimer_Callback - Inside Lock
16:00:38.562615 ConsoleTimer_Callback - processing job 467d364f-05e4-49c5-a3fd-0134d0889e4f
16:00:38.562615 WriteConsoleLines - Appending 11 lines.
16:00:38.578227 WriteConsoleLines - Leaving method.
16:00:38.578227 ConsoleTimer_Callback - leave
16:00:38.906351 StatusTimer_Callback - enter (79)
16:00:38.906351 StatusTimer_Callback - processing job 467d364f-05e4-49c5-a3fd-0134d0889e4f
16:00:38.906351 StatusTimer_Callback - processing timeline a06a0975-b891-44ac-9010-a10717e0696c
16:00:38.921996 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
16:00:38.921996 System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi.TaskOrchestrationPlanSecurityException: Access denied: TFSSERVICE does not have write permissions for orchestration plan ccf1ea00-caec-4c73-9439-ee531f24eddc.
16:00:38.921996    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
16:00:38.921996    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__49.MoveNext()
16:00:38.921996 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
16:00:38.921996    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
16:00:38.921996    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
16:00:38.921996    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
16:00:38.921996    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__47`1.MoveNext()
16:00:38.921996 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
16:00:38.921996    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
16:00:38.921996    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
16:00:38.921996    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__53`1.MoveNext()
16:00:38.921996 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
16:00:38.921996    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
16:00:38.921996    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
16:00:38.921996    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__52`1.MoveNext()
16:00:38.921996    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
16:00:38.921996    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
16:00:38.921996    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.JobWriter.CreateTimeline(Guid newTimelineId)
16:00:38.921996    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.JobInfo.CreateTimeline(JobInfo info, TimelineInfo timeline)
16:00:38.921996    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.JobInfo.StatusTimer_Callback(Object state)
16:00:38.921996 ---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi.TaskOrchestrationPlanSecurityException: Access denied: TFSSERVICE does not have write permissions for orchestration plan ccf1ea00-caec-4c73-9439-ee531f24eddc.
16:00:38.921996    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
16:00:38.921996    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__49.MoveNext()
16:00:38.921996 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
16:00:38.921996    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
16:00:38.921996    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
16:00:38.921996    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
16:00:38.921996    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__47`1.MoveNext()
16:00:38.921996 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
16:00:38.921996    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
16:00:38.921996    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
16:00:38.921996    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__53`1.MoveNext()
16:00:38.921996 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
16:00:38.921996    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
16:00:38.921996    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
16:00:38.921996    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__52`1.MoveNext()<---
16:00:38.921996 
16:00:38.921996    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
16:00:38.921996    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.JobWriter.CreateTimeline(Guid newTimelineId)
16:00:38.921996    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.JobInfo.CreateTimeline(JobInfo info, TimelineInfo timeline)
16:00:38.921996    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.JobInfo.StatusTimer_Callback(Object state)
16:00:38.921996 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
16:00:38.921996 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
16:00:38.921996 Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi.TaskOrchestrationPlanSecurityException: Access denied: TFSSERVICE does not have write permissions for orchestration plan ccf1ea00-caec-4c73-9439-ee531f24eddc.
16:00:38.921996    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
16:00:38.921996    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__49.MoveNext()
16:00:38.921996 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
16:00:38.921996    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
16:00:38.921996    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
16:00:38.921996    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
16:00:38.921996    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__47`1.MoveNext()
16:00:38.921996 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
16:00:38.921996    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
16:00:38.921996    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
16:00:38.921996    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__53`1.MoveNext()
16:00:38.921996 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
16:00:38.921996    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
16:00:38.921996    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
16:00:38.921996    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__52`1.MoveNext()
16:00:38.921996    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
16:00:38.921996    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__49.MoveNext()
16:00:38.921996 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
16:00:38.921996    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
16:00:38.921996    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
16:00:38.921996    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
16:00:38.921996    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__47`1.MoveNext()
16:00:38.921996 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
16:00:38.921996    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
16:00:38.921996    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
16:00:38.921996    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__53`1.MoveNext()
16:00:38.921996 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
16:00:38.921996    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
16:00:38.921996    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
16:00:38.921996    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__52`1.MoveNext()
16:00:38.921996 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
16:00:38.921996 StatusTimer_Callback - leave
16:00:39.093881 ConsoleTimer_Callback - enter (80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The account you're using to run the Build Agent needs to be a member of the Build Agent Service Accounts group. An administrator isn't a service account.